# how to dynamically create array variable in json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

In python, I can use the below code to dynamically create IP address array to store n number of IP addresses.

```
for i in range(12):
    addr[i] = "10.1.1." + str(i)
    print addr[i]
```

I want a similar code for JSON file. Is it possible to define variables with looping in JSON file?

Comment: What do you mean? A JSON file doesn't have variables. It can have keys, though.

Comment: And why is your question tagged python-3.x but your code has a Python 2 `print` statement?

Comment: I also don't really get what you want to do. Anyway, you can get a json-like string representation using python's [json module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html) using `json.dumps(object)`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "loop over a json file" - this makes no sense actually. You create a json string representation of a Python object - usually a dict - and eventually write it to a file (or send it as HTTP response content etc), or create a Python object from a json string:

```
>>> import json
>>> addr = ["10.1.1.{}".format(i) for i in range(12)]
>>> print(repr(json.dumps(addr)))
'["10.1.1.0", "10.1.1.1", "10.1.1.2", "10.1.1.3", "10.1.1.4", "10.1.1.5", "10.1.1.6", "10.1.1.7", "10.1.1.8", "10.1.1.9", "10.1.1.10", "10.1.1.11"]'
>>> print(repr(json.dumps({"addr": addr})))
'{"addr": ["10.1.1.0", "10.1.1.1", "10.1.1.2", "10.1.1.3", "10.1.1.4", "10.1.1.5", "10.1.1.6", "10.1.1.7", "10.1.1.8", "10.1.1.9", "10.1.1.10", "10.1.1.11"]}'
```

If you have an existing json string (from a file or any other source) and want to update it, you just parse it (with `json.loads`) to a Python object, update the python object, and dump it back to json. Assuming you have the following json string (either from a file, http response or whatever, doesn't matter):

```
>>> source = '{"foo": "bar", "addr": ["10.1.1.0", "10.1.1.1", "10.1.1.2"]}'
```

and you want to change "foo"'s value to "baaz", add addresses up to 10.1.1.11 and add a "frobnicate: true" key=>value pair:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = json.loads(source)
>>> data["foo"] = "baaz"
>>> for i in range(12):
...     ip = "10.1.1.{}".format(i)
...     if ip not in data["addr"]:
...         data["addr"].append(ip)
... 
>>> data["frobnicate"] = True
>>> updated_json = json.dumps(data)
>>> print(repr(updated_json))
'{"foo": "baaz", "addr": ["10.1.1.0", "10.1.1.1", "10.1.1.2", "10.1.1.3", "10.1.1.4", "10.1.1.5", "10.1.1.6", "10.1.1.7", "10.1.1.8", "10.1.1.9", "10.1.1.10", "10.1.1.11"], "frobnicate": true}'
>>>
```